# Reuse external file with user commands in both main file and standalone files

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files, standalone, workflow

This is a problem I encounter frequently, and for which I don't have a good (i.e., scalable and automatic) solution.

Suppose I have a main document `MWE.tex`, a macro file  with custom commands `macros.tex`, and a standalone file with a Tikz figure `tikz_external.tex`. In `macros.tex` there are commands that I want to use in both the main document, as well as in the external standalone file. Moreover, the Tikz figure requires some additional tikz library. The examples are shown below.

```
% MWE.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}

\input{macros}

\begin{document}

\includestandalone[width=0.75\linewidth]{tikz_external} 

\end{document}
```

.

```
% macros.tex
\newcommand{\foo}{FOO}
```

.

```
% tikz_external.tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % needed for Latex arrowhead style
\input{macros}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->,>=Latex] (0,0) -- node[above] {\foo} (1,0);        
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now in the main file (`MWE.tex`) this fails to compile, giving the error:

```
Command \foo already defined. \newcommand{\foo}{FOO}
```

However, if I remove the `subpreambles` option in `MWE.tex` I instead get the following error:

```
Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind 'Latex'. \draw[->,>=Latex]
```

To solve this, I can include the Tikz library `arrows.meta` into `MWE.tex`.

However, I don't like this because now `MWE.tex` has a dependency on the internals of `tikz_external.tikz`, and you could imagine there being hundreds of external Tikz files, with a varying number of Tikz libraries needed. In order to compile, `MWE.tex` would have to import all of these libraries.

I guess a third option could be to include the external Tikz figures as PDFs in the main document. But then I have to recompile the external Tikz files every time I make a change to them, which loses the benefit of building everything from within the main file.

**My question:** How should I do this properly? I.e., ideally, I want to be able to compile the external Tikz figures separately so I can work on them on their own if I want to. But I also want the ability to compile the entire document, without having to re-compile the external files. And I don't want to important all the Tikz library dependencies into the main file. Is this possible?

Comment: ProvideCommand?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your macro using `\providecommand` instead of `\newcommand` which will simply do nothing if the respective macro has been created already.

If you encounter clashes of loaded packages (for instance because you load them in `macros.tex` and in `MWE.tex` - for whatever reason) you can use `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage` and make `macros.tex` a package instead of a file that gets included via `\input`. See [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Packages#Creating_your_own_package) for further information on that.

Comment: Please note that this would throw errors. TeX is case sensitive.

Comment: @Raven if you do not place an `at`  sign before the nickname of your interlocutor (as I just did for yours) he does not receive it. So TeXnician didn't get your answer.  See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020

Comment: I've actually been using both of your suggestions previously. But for some reason I thought using ``\providecommand'' was considered bad-practice?

Comment: @hakoja The problem is that you can never be sure whether the respective command is defined the way you want it to or whether it has been defined by someone else in a completely different manner. But in this case you'd have to rely that no one else (in the loaded packages) defines the same macro and therefore you are the only one defining it. Therefore it shouldn't be that much of a problem